# How do I create a Java web service client without data binding?

Tags: java, web-services

I'm building my own web service client data binding mechanism customized for my client.  I would like to build my own SOAP message on the request and receive the SOAP message response.  I started writing a client directly interacting with the socket, but started getting hung up with the complexities of WS-Security.  Any ideas on libraries and/or approaches for this project?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  It would really help if you could elaborate on what you have tried so far, and what exactly hung you up.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

What makes you think that you need custom bindings? Probably those tested with 1000-s of developers are quite mature.

Take a look at [Apache CXF](http://cxf.apache.org/). Go through [architecture documentation](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/cxf-architecture.html). You may find an extension point there suitable for your needs.

Apache CXF currently supported data bindings: JAXB 2.x (default), Aegis, Apache XMLBeans, Service Data Objects (SDO) and JiBX (under development). If any of those doesn't fit your needs attach your own following [data binding architecture docs](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/data-binding-architecture.html).